# How do I use an onclick to do two things at once in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use an onClick on an element to do two things once you click on it.

I know that this is how you do one, but how do you do two or more?

```
<div onClick={myFunction}></div>
```

I am using React 17 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Do the things in the `myFunction` body

Answer (score 2):

You create an alternative 'myFunction' that does the two things that you want.  E.g.

```
function myFunction() {
    thing1();
    thing2();
}
```

or you put a lambda function in:

```
onClick={() => {thing1(); thing2()}}
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be an "alternative" `myFunction`. It can be the actual `myFunction` which does two things.

Comment: I was assuming (although I never do that!) that 'myFunction' was one of the two things to be done.  And then I kind of threw that assumption away in the answer!  I think the concept comes though either way though.

Answer (score 1):

Replace it with an arrow function.

```
<div onClick={()=>{myFunction();mySecondFunction();}}></div>
```